# How to format line in algorithm

Tags: pdftex, algorithms, algorithmicx

I use ACM conference paper template (Two columns) to write paper. The problems bug me for a long time about Algorithms format:

- The function name always converted to UPPERCASE.
- Larger blank between words
- `\OR`, or `\AND` is not recognized for `If` condition.

An example is below:

```
\documentclass[10pt, preprint]{sigplanconf}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
%\usepackage[chapter]{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithms
%\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\special{papersize=8.5in,11in}
\setlength{\pdfpageheight}{\paperheight}
\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{\paperwidth}

\conferenceinfo{CONF 'yy}{Month d--d, 20yy, City, ST, Country} 
\copyrightyear{20yy} 
\copyrightdata{978-1-nnnn-nnnn-n/yy/mm} 
\doi{nnnnnnn.nnnnnnn}

\preprintfooter{short description of paper}   % 'preprint' option specified.

\title{AAA}
 \authorinfo{}
            {}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
AAA
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}


This is test for  Algorithm~\ref{alg:equivalentmap}. Hello world..

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Equivalent Method Handle (MH) Detection}
\label{alg:equivalentmap}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State $mh$: A method handle to be proceeded.
\State $TN$: Transformation Name.

\Procedure{Detection}{$a$, $b$}
    \If{eqMap.containsKey($a$.TN) or countMH($a$)!=countMH($b$)}
      \State return false
    \EndIf

    \If{$a$.isDirectMH() and $b$.isDirect()}
       \State return $a$.targetMethod().equal($b$.targetMethod())
    \EndIf

    \ForAll{method handle $mh0$ in $mh$ graph}
              \If {$equivMap$ contains $mh0.TN$} 
                   \ForAll {$equivSet$ in the $equivMap$.get($mh0.TN$)}
                      \If{precheck($mh0$, $equivSet$) is false}  
                          \State   continue
                      \EndIf

                      \If{ $mh0$ is equivalent to a MH in $equivSet$}
                           \State  add $mh0$ to this $equivSet$
                           \State  break;                   
                      \EndIf
                  \EndFor
                  \If{none of equivalent set is matched}
                      \State initialize new $equivSet$ with $mh0$.
                      \State append this new set to $equivMap$.get($mh0.TN$) list. 
                  \EndIf
             \Else
                  \State  initialize new equivalent set \emph{equivSet} with $mh0$
                  \State  add new pair ($mh0.TN$, \emph{equivSet}) to $equivMap$. 
             \EndIf
   \EndFor
\EndProcedure
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}


\end{document}
```

As shown in the screenshot below the function name in the line 3 is converted to uppercase automatically (I do not want this modification).

[image]

In the line 4 (12 and 23), there is a large blank inside of IF condition. I failed to remove these blanks as it seems it is automatically inserted.

Also, How can i use add/or/not logics in the condition test. As you can see, the condition in line 4 is composition of some logic that are OR and AND. I tried to replace line 4:

```
``\If{eqMap.containsKey($a$.TN) or countMH($a$)!=countMH($b$)}''
```

with

```
``\If{eqMap.containsKey($a$.TN) \OR countMH($a$)!=countMH($b$)}''
```

but failed. The compiler says `undefined control flow` for \OR.

[cls file is provided in this link](http://www.sigplan.org/sites/default/files/sigplanconf.cls)

Comment: Can you provide a link to `sigplanconf.cls`?

Comment: Thanks for your remind @Werner. The official link for the CLS file is:   http://www.sigplan.org/sites/default/files/sigplanconf.cls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is due to the narrow size of the column.

You have two choices.

1. Declare `\footnotesize` before `\begin{algoritmic}`

   ```
   \begin{algorithm}
   \caption{Equivalent Method Handle (MH) Detection}
   \label{alg:equivalentmap}
   \footnotesize
   \begin{algorithmic}[1]
   \State $mh$: A method handle to be proceeded.
   ...
   \EndProcedure
   \end{algorithmic}
   \end{algorithm}
   ```

   [image]
2. Use `algorithm*` instead of `algorithm`, which will typeset the algorithm in double column width at the top of a page.

   ```
   \begin{algorithm*}
   \caption{Equivalent Method Handle (MH) Detection}
   \label{alg:equivalentmap}
   \begin{algorithmic}[1]
   \State $mh$: A method handle to be proceeded.
   ...
   \EndProcedure
   \end{algorithmic}
   \end{algorithm*}
   ```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm continuing egreg's answer, which fixes "bug" #2 by reducing font size or widening the text and thus avoiding line breaks.

1. You can format the procedure's name in any way you like, by redefining the `\textproc` macro, e.g.:

   ```
   \algrenewcommand\textproc{\textit}
   ```

   If you don't like the italics that I chose, try `\textrm` instead.
2. If you don't want to use egreg's suggestion and you want to stick with your font size and a single-column algorithm, you can add `\raggedright` just before your `\begin{algorithmic}`, to avoid right justification in your algorithm.  This, however, will result in wrapped lines which are not indented and look ugly.  You may break the lines explicitly by using `\\`.  I recommend egreg's suggestion, though.
3. The logical connectives that you mention are not supported by `algorithmicx` (but by `algorithmics`, which is not compatible with your source).  You can define them with:

   ```
   \usepackage{xspace}
   \algnewcommand\OR{\textbf{or}\xspace}
   \algnewcommand\AND{\textbf{and}\xspace}
   \algnewcommand\NOT{\textbf{not}\xspace}
   ```

   Let me also suggest that you do the same for "break" and "continue", so they appear in bold:

   ```
   \algnewcommand\Break{\textbf{break}\xspace}
   \algnewcommand\Continue{\textbf{continue}\xspace}
   ```

   and that you use `\State \Return` instead of `\State return` to have the "return" keyword also in bold.

Finally, let me suggest that you either use math mode consistently in your algorithm or avoid it altogether.  For example, `$mh0.TN$` looks very ugly (look how `$TN$` is typeset in line 2 of the attached figure --- the juxtaposition of letters in math mode is meant as multiplication, and this leaves extra space between the letters).  Either remove the math mode, or use `$\mathit{mh0}.\mathit{TN}$`.

[image]

Comment: I adopt @egreg option 1 and your solutions. Both are useful. Thanks.